# Local network addresses unreachable after fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04

I have two laptops in a wireless network. Internet access works fine for both of them. As long as both were running 'Ubuntu desktop 20.04' they also could reach each other in the local network (ping 192.168...).

Recently i installed 'Ubuntu desktop 22.04' on one of them (fresh install not upgrading). Still both have access to the internet over the wireless router but they can't reach each other anymore using ping (Destination Host Unreachable) or ssh (ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.213 port 22: No route to host).

What can i do to make this possible again?

Additional info :

**Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04** :

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:3d:4a:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:d7:86:0e:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.213/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 3189sec preferred_lft 3189sec
    inet6 2a02:908:671:ae80:bcc5:1967:7578:d90f/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 74660sec preferred_lft 31460sec
    inet6 2a02:908:671:ae80:1221:e3ff:b1c1:ec8c/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 74660sec preferred_lft 31460sec
    inet6 fe80::66c9:eda5:134f:7837/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:41:7d:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:41:7d:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: mpqemubr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:a2:48:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.141.1/24 brd 10.10.141.255 scope global mpqemubr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:9b:c6:47:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.10.141.0/24 dev mpqemubr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.141.1 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.213 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 

$ ip neigh
192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 lladdr 34:2c:c4:31:64:d1 DELAY
fe80::362c:c4ff:fe31:64d1 dev wlp3s0 lladdr 34:2c:c4:31:64:d1 router REACHABLE
```

**Laptop with Ubuntu 22.04** :

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:78:4e:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:88:b4:d2:f7:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.24/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 2601sec preferred_lft 2601sec
    inet6 2a02:908:671:ae80:861f:42bf:a369:89fe/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 74080sec preferred_lft 30880sec
    inet6 2a02:908:671:ae80:aaa3:6bfa:1117:d7a1/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 74080sec preferred_lft 30880sec
    inet6 fe80::ca1:8cc6:59db:6bf6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: wwx028037ec0200: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:80:37:ec:02:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.24 metric 600 
$ ip neigh
192.168.0.213 dev wlp3s0  FAILED
192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 lladdr 34:2c:c4:31:64:d1 REACHABLE
fe80::362c:c4ff:fe31:64d1 dev wlp3s0 lladdr 34:2c:c4:31:64:d1 router REACHABLE
```

p.s. Firewall is inactive on both sides:
$ sudo ufw status

> Status: inactive

Comment: Hi! Please post the output of the following commands, from both laptops.
`ip addr`
`ip route`
`ip neigh`
How is the network configured on these laptops? DHCP or static IP? Is there only one router? How many access points?

Comment: Added the outputs of ip addr, ip route, ip neigh. For the 'Ubuntu 22.04' it seems to me to indicate the problem in ip neigh. There is only one router in my simple wireless home network. DHCP or static IP...? How can i find out?

Comment: To answer my own question: the network should be configured DHCP because i got the router just from a commercial provider.

Answer (score 0):

I too have had a similar problem however, in my case, all versions of ubuntu suffer ie. cannot ping or otherwise get to ubuntu systems in my network.  It started when I switched from a 2wire DSL modem to a TP-Link router.  My work around has been to hard code the local ip addresses in /etc/hosts. One of my ubuntu systems is 22.04, the other is 16.04.

Comment: Updating /etc/hosts didn't help in my case... BTW

Comment: BTW How do you think it could help? Isn't it just a way to 'rename' an IP address while the IP address cannot be resolved?

Comment: It helps because it worked for me.  I too wish there was a better answer but, unless and until a better answer is found, updating /etc/hosts has been my long term work-around.  Modifying /etc/hosts can also be used to alter adress resolution.  In short, there is more than one reason to place entries in /etc/hosts 1) to alter address resolution and 2) resolve addresses when another way isn't apparent.